# Button value is not changing

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The button value of the button with class dropbtn is not changing. Whenever you hover over the button and click a region, the standard value "Select Region" should change to the region you clicked.

Example can be found at http://www.broadcasteralerts.com

Snippet of code below (Doesn't work on JSFiddle cause of the ?link=NA in the anchors.

I need these href's to be the current ?link=region. Because I need to do specific api searches with that in the future.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var regionDropDown = $('.region_dropdown_section'),
      regionButton = regionDropDown.find('button'),
      regionList = regionDropDown.find('.region_dropdown_content').children();

  $(regionList).on('click', function(e){
    var region = e.target;
    regionButton.text(region.text).val(region.text);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url(../images/background/body_background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.SearchSummoners {
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
background-color: #19A5D4;
color: white;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}



/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.region_dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    max-width: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.region_dropdown_section {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.region_dropdown_content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.region_dropdown_content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .region_dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #1491BA;
}

.Searchbox_Summoners {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}


#SearchBox {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     width: 80%;
     background-color: white;
     height: 40px;
     float: left;
    }

        .region_dropdown_section {
         position: inherit;
         display: inline-block;
         max-width: 100% !important;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

#SearchInput{
  width: 92%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
 }

  /* Region Sprites */

.BR, .EUNE, .EUW, .JP, .KR, .LAN, .LAS, .NA, .OCEANIA, .RUS, .TURKEY{
 background: url(../images/icons/regions/regions.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.BR{
 background-position: -2px -2px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.EUNE{
 background-position: -2px -35px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.EUW{
 background-position: -2px -70px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.JP{
 background-position: -2px -105px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.KR{
 background-position: -2px -140px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.LAN{
 background-position: -2px -175px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.LAS{
 background-position: -2px -210px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.NA{
 background-position: -2px -245px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.OCEANIA{
 background-position: -2px -280px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.RUS{
 background-position: -2px -315px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.TURKEY{
 background-position: -2px -350px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
  <div class="SearchSummoners">
      <div id="SearchBox">
        <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
          <input id="SearchInput" value="Enter Summoners Name"  onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter Summoners Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Summoners Name'; }"  type="text" name="SummonerName"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="region_dropdown_section">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
        <div class="region_dropdown_content">
          <a href="?link=NA"><span class="NA"></span>North America</a>
          <a href="?link=EUW"><span class="EUW"></span>Europe West</a>
          <a href="?link=EUNE"><span class="EUNE"></span>Europe NE</a>
          <a href="?link=LAN"><span class="LAN"></span>LAN</a>
          <a href="?link=LAS"><span class="LAS"></span>LAS</a>
          <a href="?Link=OC"><span class="OCEANIA"></span>Oceania</a>
          <a href="?link=BR"><span class="BR"></span>Brazil</a>
          <a href="?link=KR"><span class="KR"></span>Korea</a>
          <a href="?link=JP"><span class="JP"></span>Japan</a>
          <a href="?link=TUR"><span class="TURKEY"></span>Turkey</a>
          <a href="?link=RUS"><span class="RUS"></span>Russia</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: you are not stopping the default action of your links which would be going to your `href` you need prevent this with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: So would this work? I'm sorry if I sound derpy, I'm not good with javascript at all: `$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});`

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
$(regionList).on('click', function(e){
    var region = e.target;
    regionButton.text(region.text).val(region.text);
  });
```

TO

```
$('.region_dropdown_content a').on('click', function(e){
        var region = $(this).text();
        regionButton.text(region );
});
```

Comment: That's not changing the button text at all. It should change the default <button> value called "Select Region" to the region you click.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work for me - I changed the exact code and it's not changing the button value at all.

Comment: can you alert the value of region?

Comment: The thing is, it stopped working when I added the ?link=region to the anchor attributes. But I need those for the API calls in the future.

Comment: you need to chnage the href of <a> tag to "javascript:;" and store link value to somewhere else for api call

Comment: So basically `<a href="javascript:;">Region</a>`. I did that and the region button text is not changing now also,  How would I store the link value somewhere else then? (I'm sorry I'm terrible at javascript

Comment: you can create a hidden text field somewhere in the html page and store the link value  as value of hidden field using jquery : <input type="hidden" name="link">

Comment: So i would created 8 different hidden inputs with the name ?link=NA and then put them in the attribute using javascript? How would I go about doing that

Comment: only one hidden field is enough

Answer (score 0):

The value of an input type button is actually the text in the button.

```
regionButton.val(region.text);
```

Comment: OP is using a <button> tag, based on the selector: regionDropDown.find('button')

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take out the hard coded 'Select Region' for the button, and just set it as a default value within your javascript code. At the moment it seems to change your value temporarily, but then reload and go back to the hard coded value.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, use e.preventDefault(); in you code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var regionDropDown = $('.region_dropdown_section'),
      regionButton = regionDropDown.find('button'),
      regionList = regionDropDown.find('.region_dropdown_content').children();

  $(regionList).on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var region = e.target;
    regionButton.text(region.text).val(region.text);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, this worked already, but what about the ?link=region in my html at the anchors. I need those for API requests to region specific API servers. Is it still possible to use that, or is there a way to make the href show up in the browser URL baR?